# How to switch between head and eye gaze? MRTK3 HoloLens2

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I use MRTK3 in Unity for HoloLens2 development. I want to switch between eye gaze and head gaze. I found out how to enable eye gaze from a sample project. But I don't know how to disable eye gaze and start head gaze to use the head as a cursor to select something. How can I enable the head gaze and disable the other inputs?

Comment: Can't confirm for sure nor test rn but as far as I understand MS's [EyeTracking Docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk3-input/packages/input/eye-tracking#overview) head gaze is only a fallback. However, it says "if eye gaze is disabled, not configured or not ccalibrated, the controller will use the head gaze pose instead". This sounds like you could potentially disable eye gaze. You could however also just implement head gaze for yourself. If you need help on that let us know.

Comment: hm okay, do you have a hint how to disable only eye gaze and not the gaze interactor? I haven't thought about implementing head gaze myself yet, how can this be done?

Comment: No, don’t know anything about disabling eye gaze without disabling the gaze interactor. I saw that you can remove either the head gaze or eye gaze composite entirely but then you wouldn’t be able to switch (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/11582)). Maybe this can be done programmatically… Anyways, to implement head gaze you could still utilize the gaze origin provided and ray cast into space using the forward vector which would mimic a head gaze